# Add Attribute to Base Property from Derived Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, attributes

I'd like to add attributes to the properties of a class I'm inheriting from (that I cannot edit because it is generated). I've attempted to do this by redeclaring them in the child class with the "new" keyword and adding the attribute.

This seemed to be working until I noticed some issues it was causing when reflecting on an instance of the child and noticed that the property was not being copied. See the following example:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public class BaseClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class ChildClass : BaseClass
        {
            [MyAttribute]
            new public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new ChildClass();
            source.Name = "foo";

            var target = new ChildClass();
            var properties = typeof(BaseClass).GetProperties();

            foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(source);
                property.SetValue(target, value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(target.Name); // Prints nothing
        }
    }
}
```

If I inspect the source object after I set the "Name" property, it appears both the parent and child's "Name" property exist on the child, and that only the child's is populated (see image below). I assume the parent's property in the one being copies, since it's null in the target object. I assume this is all due to the use (or misuse) of redeclaring the property with "new".

**I'm assuming I'm misusing the new keyword here, but is there another way to add an attribute to base class's property from a child class without the ability to edit the parent class?**

[image: Properties with the same name]

Comment: You need to override it.

Comment: @SLaks I would need to declare it as virtual in the base class, but I can't edit the base class.

Comment: The base class sealed the property precisely to *prevent* derived classes from making changes to it.  That you can't change it is the way it was designed.  It would be a problem if you *could* change it.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that's the case. According the the [C# spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#hiding-through-inheritance) you're allowed to hide base class members from derived classes.  I have no problem doing this, accessing the value from the derived class normally, or seeing the attribute I added to the derived class. The only real issue is the problem accessing the value via reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shadow the property but use the base property's value:

```
[MyAttribute]
new public string Name { 
    get => base.Name; 
    set => base.Name = value;
}
```